# How to Add a PictureBox to Multiple Tabs?

Tags: powershell, picturebox, powershell-4.0

Having some issues with a program I'm creating for our organisations IT Service Desk.

Basically it's a troubleshooting tool, and it has multiple tabs.
I want each tab page to have our company logo on the top of the tabpage.
However, when I create the picturebox and then add it to the tab, then try and add it to another tab, it removes from the first.

Some code example below:

```
$LogoBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox  
$LogoBox.Image = $CompanyImage  
$LogoBox.SizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage  
$LogoBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,100)    
$LogoBox.Location = (($Form.Width / 2) - ($LogoBox.Width / 2))  
$EmailGeneralTab.Controls.Add($LogoBox)  
$UserTab.Controls.Add($LogoBox)
```

In this example, the LogoBox will only end up on the UserTab, and it will not show up on the EmailGeneral Tab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're only creating one LogoBox object but have several tabs. You need to create a new picturebox object containing the logo for each tab